I can't figure out how to generate a new random value every time random.choice is called and why the function isn't called
import random

# The card pool
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
# I created a list for the players cards bc that was the cleanest solution
players_cards = []
card_value = random.choice(cards)
sum = 0


def add(n1, n2):
    totals = n1 + n2
    return  totals

# I thought a function with a for loop in it to collect the players sum total of cards     was the cleanest solution
def player_total():
    for i in players_cards:
        sum += i


dictionary = {
    'total': player_total
}

should_continue = True
players_cards.append(card_value)
adding_players_total = dictionary['total']

# This is the while loop needed for the player to 'HIT' so to speak before passing the     computer
while should_continue == True:
    players_cards.append(card_value)
    print(f"Your cards are {players_cards}, current score: {adding_players_total}")
    print(f"The computer's first card is: {card_value}")
    players_choices = input("Type 'y' for another card, or 'n' to pass: ").lower()
    if players_choices == 'y':
        should_continue == True
    else:
        break

This is very much a work in progress still. I'm on Day 11 of Angela Yu's 100 days of code bootcamp. I'm working towards building a blackjack game.I'd estimate I'm maybe 35% done.
The first issue I'm struggling with, and I just don't understand how to solve is the PRNG. From my limited understanding, the PRNG is based on system time, but if one needs to call random.choice multiple times, such as in a loop like this case, it will return the same value, which it does. I have no idea how to solve that. I read something about random.seed, but that seems counter to what I want. It would ensure the PRNG generates the same value every time.
This second issue is this line: {adding_players_total}"), way down by the while loop. I can't seem to get this function to call. I wanted to create a For loop that would iterate through the list, or 'cards' in the players in hand. I thought this would be a clean and elegant solution to tally the total value of playing cards that the play has. I couldn't seem to figure out how to call it correctly in the program though, so I started getting desperate and trying things like the dictionary. I'm now really lost.

I should add, what I mean by the same number is the player will get 3, 3 or 4, 4 and later 4, 4, 4. This is obviously undesirable because the odds of this actually happening in a blackjack game are extremely slim.

Why do you need the player_total() function at all?  Just use the built-in sum() function, like this:  adding_players_total = sum(players_cards)

This code only calls random.choice() once, so it's not clear what you mean when you say the player will get 4, 4, 4.  Are you are running this code multiple times?  If so, how?

What do you mean you get the same value from random.choice each time? When I call it I get different values. See: https://pastebin.com/7iPsYSt5.

And this dictionary['total'] doesn't actually call the function -- you need parentheses () to make a function call, so that would be dictionary['total']().  But you don't need the dictionary, or the function, at all.  Just use sum() as I mentioned above.

This is way too long to be a [mre]. A good code sample on Stack Overflow requires you to do some debugging to localize the problem first; "code dumps" are difficult to answer and don't contribute to our goal of creating a long-lasting, broadly useful knowledge database.

card_value = random.choice(cards) should be within your while loop, not before it.

I think you'll need to do a bit of refactoring after this to get the game to work how you want it to in the end.
If you call random once at top of the page then that sets that value permanently. You need to call random again if you want another random number.
Not sure where you were going there with the dictionary.  I adjusted your function and then added it to the f-string so it's called (recalculated) each time that loop is run.
import random

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
players_cards = []
computers_cards = []

def add(n1, n2):
    totals = n1 + n2
    return  totals

# I adjusted the function name for clarity
def caluclate_player_total(cards):
    total = 0
    for i in cards:
        total += i
    return total

should_continue = True
players_cards.append(random.choice(cards))
computers_cards.append(random.choice(cards))

while should_continue == True:
    players_cards.append(random.choice(cards))
    print(f"Your cards are {players_cards}, current score: {caluclate_player_total(players_cards)}")
    print(f"The computer's first card is: {computers_cards}")
    players_choices = input("Type 'y' for another card, or 'n' to pass: ").lower()
    if players_choices != 'y':
        break


You are choosing a random card outside of the main loop. This means you will choose a card once when the program starts and than keep reusing the same card over and over because you never choose another random card. Instead you need to choose a random card within the loop in order to do the operation repeatedly.
For example, here in this snipped of code where a random card is picked once and continually reused.
import random

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

chosen_card = random.choice(cards)

while True:
  # "chosen_card" will never change because I never assign a new value to it.
  print(chosen_card)

Let us look at an example where you would actually choose a random card
over and over in a loop.
import random

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

while True:
  # Here on the other hand "random.choice(cards)" is executed inside the
  # loop and its result is assigned to chosen_card repeatedly.
  chosen_card = random.choice(cards)
  print(chosen_card)


Here is an fixed and improved version of your original code.
import random

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
players_cards = []


def player_total():
    return sum(players_cards)

while True:
    card_value = random.choice(cards) # To randomize the computer's first card each time the player choose a card
    players_cards.append(random.choice(cards))
    
    print(f"Your cards are {players_cards}, current score: {player_total()}")
    print(f"The computer's first card is: {card_value}")
    
    players_choices = input("Type 'y' for anothery card, or 'n' to pass: ").lower()
    
    if players_choices == 'y':
      continue

    elif players_choices == 'n':
        break
    
    else:
      print("Please enter a y or n")
      continue

I have removed the redundant things like unnecessary add function, sum variable etc. Also NEVER use keywords as variable names (one more small suggestion - never name the file same name of a module, i.e., never name a file random.py for example).
Also it'd be better to post such questions and queries to this place or here. Since you're just starting out, and the UI might be friendlier to you.

If this is meant to emulate a card game where cards are selected at random from a deck you need to account for two things:

there are 4 suits and therefore 52 cards (not just the 13 you have)
once you've drawn a card from the "deck" it needs to be removed so that it can't be selected again

Something like this:
import random

deck = [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11] for _ in range(4)]

cards = []

def decksize() -> int:
    return sum(len(s) for s in deck)

while decksize() > 0 and (answer := input("Hit? ")) == "y":
    s = random.choice(deck) # pick a suit
    c = random.choice(s) # pick a card
    cards.append(c) # remember the selected card
    s.remove(c) # remove the selected card from the relevant suit
    # if there are no more cards in the chosen suit, remove it from the deck
    if len(s) == 0:
        deck.remove(s)
    print(sum(cards)) # current sum

print(*cards) # summary of selected card values


@JonSG Fair comment. I should have been more thoughtful. I think it would be pointless to make substantial edits to it now though
